# Find length of common chord of nine point circle.

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

$K$ is any point on side $\overline{BC}$ of triangle $\triangle ABC$ . Find the length of the common chord of the nine-point circle of triangle $\triangle ABK$ and triangle $\triangle AKC$ if $\overline{AK} = 10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common chord is just the segment joining the midpoint of $AK$ with the projection $H_A$ of $A$ on $BC$. Since $\widehat{K H_A A}=90^\circ$, the length of the common chord is just $\color{red}{5}$.

[image]